# Silverlight toolkit sets styles for grid, not just actual control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I've just installed the Silverligt toolkit 4 to get access to some of the nicely styled controls.

However, when I surround a button in a grid with the theme, I get the following result:

http://screencast.com/t/aiWsArdb

Both of the squares are grid controls, with a solid color background. But when I apply a theme to the button in the left grid, the entire grid gets styled. That's not really what I am after. Anyone know how I can avoid this? Basically I just want the theme to apply to the button only, and not the parent grid.

The XAML is:

```
<dark:ExpressionDarkTheme><Button Content="Button" Name="button1"/></dark:ExpressionDarkTheme>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExpressionDarkTheme has a default Black Background, try setting it to null.

```
    <toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme Background="{x:Null}">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
```

Comment: @MortenK, how did you go with it? :)

Comment: I got pulled away due to a customer deadline, so I haven't even gotten the chance to try it out yet :-( But I've marked it as answer anyhow, I think it will work :-) Hopefully I can test it next weekend.

Comment: @MortenK, if it doesn't, let me know! ;)